# Using plain SQL query with LIKE operator and % wildcards in Slick

Tags: sql, scala, jdbc, sql-like, slick

I am trying to use a **plain SQL** query in `Slick`. The query has a `LIKE` operator with `%` wildcards.

```
  val someText: String = "some text"
  val query = sql"""SELECT mt.id, mt.name FROM my_table mt
          WHERE mt.name LIKE '%$someText%';""".as[MyEntity]
  val queryResult : Future[Vector[MyEntity]] = db.run(query)
```

What I am getting is the following:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument in JDBC call: parameter index out of range: 1
```

**Is there a safe way to write this query (in plain SQL, and use it in Slick)?**

I have tried several combinations based on close answers I've found, but none worked. It's not clear to me if the single quotes are actually required in this case since usually with Slick they are not required. But when I tested the query without the single quotes it did not work. It did work with something like `... WHERE mt.name LIKE '%Stuff%';"""`, where I hardcoded the string I am searching to be `Stuff`.

My guess is that a parameter surrounded by single quotes confuses Slick. But I could find out how to make it work in Slick.

Comment: I thin you should use something like this: `like '%#${someText}%'`. But it's better to use slick APIs rather than raw querying

Comment: @AminMal Yes! The missing part was `#`... I have not seen it before. Do you know where it is mentioned in the Slick documentation?

Comment: Here, https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.1.1/sql.html#splicing-literal-values

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have to use plain SQL, the way to handle this is to create a seperate value for the like expression with the appropriate wild cards, and then use that in your plain query:

```
val someText: String = "some text"
val likeExpr = s"%${someText}%"
```

and then:

```
val query = sql"""SELECT mt.id, mt.name FROM my_table mt
          WHERE mt.name LIKE $likeExpr;""".as[MyEntity]
```

Note that `likeExpr` will be correctly quoted and escaped for you.

If you use a splice (`#`) -- which totally works, too -- there is no character escaping, meaning if `someText` comes from a user (or other untrusted source), you are open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: What is the actual effect of `#`? What is the part that does the escape in your code? And what about more common queries such as `sql"""SELECT mt.id FROM my_table mt WHERE mt.name = $name;"""`... are they escaped?

Comment: The effect of # is to drop in the value as it is, without quotes or other "changes" to the value. For example: `sql"""select $someText""".as[String]` translates to `SELECT 'Hello'` (with `val someText = "Hello"`). Whereas `sql"""select #$someText""".as[String]` translates to `select Hello` (which likely produces a "column not found" error).  I suspect (not checked) it's the `sql` string interpolator that is doing the work automtically when subsitituing in values (and you have to go out of your way with # to "turn it off")